# Parallelism is required for DevOps Power Platform Build Tools

Tags: azure-devops, build-tools, power-platform

I created this pipeline in DevOps Using Power Platform Build Tools: [Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYFZo.png)

When I was running the pipeline I got an error about Parallelism: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0v1k.png)

I know this error and I know how to fix it - I want to ask what is happening in the parallel direction at the same time, so I need it? Or how I can avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get free tier access you can submit request on below Microsoft portal. Generally, it takes 2-3 business days.

https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request

You need to apply for free Parallelism separately for Private and Public projects in your organization.

To learn more about parallel jobs, refer to this official link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted